# Is Accurev a distributed version control system?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, accurev

1. Is Accurev a distributed version control system such as Git or a centralized one such as SVN?
2. Does Accurev hold any advantages over Git or SVN? If so what are they?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AccuRev_SCM. Centralised. Usual arguments apply.

Comment: AccuRev is often used for DevOps since when you check in a change, it will kickoff a new build with a build engine like Jenkins. This is often referred to as continuous integration, and also continuous delivery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AccuRev_SCM), AccuRev is a centralized version control system (à la SVN).

It is very probably a proprietary software (with all the disadvantages, in particular vendor lock-in), unlike GIT and SVN (which both are free software), so it is probably not widely used.

I recommend using GIT instead (but I never heard of AccuRev before).